# Cordova plugin with .so file not working in Steroids

Tags: java, cordova, steroids

I've build a cordova plugin to be used in a steroids app. The plugin is working if it is used in a cordova app. But it's crashing if it's used in the steroids app.

I have two external files included in the plugin.xml.

```
<source-file src="libs/test.jar" target-dir="libs/"/>
<source-file src="libs/armeabi/test.so" target-dir="libs/armeabi"/>
```

And I narrowed down the problem. The jar file is getting seen if the plugin is used in in cordova app/steroids app. However I don't know if the .so file is being seen. Because when I instantiate an object of a class with a call to.

```
System.loadLibrary("test");
```

the app crashes. Please take note that the plugin is working in the cordova app but not in steroids app.

Is there anything wrong with what I'm doing? Or it's steroids limitations in using cordova plugins with .so file?

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm trying to create a cordova plugin that uses a library with jni compiled files (.so) and they do not seem to be getting transfered to the device. I've added the paths and filenames to plugin.xml and still crashes when accessing a method in the jni file.